# New class prevent XeLaTeX to compile the section title

Tags: sectioning, xetex, titlesec

I created a new class, called `capitulo` to prevent a page break with every chapter. But when I activate those code lines, the section number won't print.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,twocolumn]{constitution}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2cm, inner=3cm,outer=2.5cm]{geometry}% See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options.
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\begin{document}

\capitulo{Generalidades}
\article{Denominação e Sede}
\section{} A ABCD, adiante também designada por ABCD, foi fundada a X de X de 1994 e tem a sua sede na cidade XY.
```

and the `constitution.cls` is:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]

\ProvidesClass{constitution}[2009/05/15 v0.0.1 Document class for typesetting a constitution]

\LoadClass{report}

\RequirePackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\RequirePackage{paralist}

%\newcommand{\bylaw}[1]{\part{#1} \setcounter{section}{0}}
%\renewcommand{\partname}{Bylaw}

\titleclass\capitulo{straight}[\part]
\titleformat{\capitulo}[display]{\filcenter\LARGE\normalfont\bfseries}{Cap\'{\i}tulo \thecapitulo}{0pt}{\filcenter\Large\normalfont\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\capitulo}{0mm}{*4}{*2.3}[0mm]
\newcounter{capitulo}
\renewcommand\thecapitulo{\Roman{capitulo}}

\titlecontents{capitulo}
[1.5em]
{\bfseries}
{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titleclass\article{straight}[\part]
\titleformat{\article}[display]{\filcenter\normalfont\bfseries}{Artigo \thearticle}{0pt}{\filcenter\normalfont\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\article}{0mm}{*4}{*2.3}[0mm]
\newcounter{article}
\renewcommand\thearticle{\arabic{article}}

\titlecontents{article}
[1.5em]
{\bfseries}
{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

%TEXTO QUE ESTAVA COMENTADO
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection
{section}{1}{0mm}%
{-\baselineskip}%
{-0.5\baselineskip}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}%
\makeatother
%TEXTO QUE ESTAVA COMENTADO

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{article}
\makeatother
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\scshape}
{Sec\c{c}\~ao \thesection.}{.5em}{}[\quad]

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} 
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\roman{enumii}}
```

My question is: I want the sections to be presented as `Seccção 1` and the chapter titles to get formatted as is.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Your document is incomplete.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use a standard class and something like `titlesec` to customise things? That is what you seem to be trying to do. Or wrap it in a package. I don't see the need for a class here.

Comment: Do you really want the `capitulo`, `article` and `section` counters be reset with part? This means that they correspond to three parallel levels, just under `part`?